# Sublime Text 2 Custom Completion: jQuery like Syntax

Tags: autocomplete, escaping, sublimetext2

I'm writing my own custom auto completion for Sublime Text 2 for Kirby CMS. The syntax is the following: `$page->title()`, for example. Now, just a plain completion would be like this (this is already working):

```
{ "trigger": "page->title()", "contents": "page->title()" },
```

My problem is, that Sublime Text doesn't recognize the `>` – everything works fine, till I type the > character, the auto-completion just stops there (the auto-complete-tooltip is hidden). I'm not an expert at all, and only tried the basic escaping stuff I now (just like you would escape the $ symbol: `\\$var` and `page-\\>title()`), but all I get is `page-\>...`. One backslash leads to an error.

Now my question: is it possible to escape the > in a way that I can type `page->` and get the corresponding suggestions, or do I have to do something else? Or is it not possible at all?

Thanks for you answer!